# How to redirect JSON serialization of a class to a different one?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a situation where I need to serialize out any `GameObject` as something else internally (`GameObjectMetadata`) that contains data helpful to deserializing it again later.

```
public struct GameObjectMetadata
{
    public string AssetFullPath;
    public string AssetBundle;
    public string GUID;
    public string UnityType;
}

public struct TestPrefabLink
{
    public GameObject Prefab;
}
```

I'm really struggling to implement the JSON.NET converters required to make this happen. I've been at it awhile and have come up with the below code. It mostly works, but I get the following error:

> JsonSerializationException: Unexpected token while deserializing
>   object: EndObject. Path 'Components.$values[0]', line 14, position 7.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
>   System.Object existingValue) (at
>   C:/Development/Releases/Json/Working/Newtonsoft.Json/Working-Signed/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:336)

Serializer:

```
data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blueprint, Formatting.Indented,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new GameObjectMetadataJsonConverter(), new UnityObjectJsonConverter() }
            });
```

Converters used:

```
public class GameObjectMetadataJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {       
        var jobj = JObject.FromObject(value);
        jobj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var metadata = serializer.Deserialize<GameObjectMetadata>(reader);

        // Snipped - Code here successfully converts to GameObject
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (GameObjectMetadata);
    }
}

public class UnityObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(UnityEngine.Object).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return existingValue; // This should not be called. But it is??
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var metadata = new GameObjectMetadata();
        metadata.UnityType = value.GetType().ToString();

        var path = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath((UnityEngine.Object)value);
        var bundleName = UnityEditor.AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path).assetBundleName;
        var guid = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(path);

        metadata.AssetBundle = bundleName;
        metadata.AssetFullPath = path;
        metadata.GUID = guid;

        //var jobj = JObject.FromObject(metadata);
        //jobj.WriteTo(writer);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, metadata);
    }
}
```

It seems whatever I'm doing here is causing some bad JSON write out. But I cannot figure out how else to write out a different struct/class from the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UnityObjectJsonConverter.ReadJson()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) will indeed be called because, during deserialization, [`CanConvert(objectType)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) will be called with the *expected type to be deserialized* not the *actual type serialized to the file*.  And the expected type will be some subtype of `UnityEngine.Object`.

Thus you need to do something like:

```
public struct GameObjectMetadata
{
    public GameObjectMetadata(UnityEngine.Object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        this.UnityType = value.GetType();

        var path = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(value);
        var bundleName = UnityEditor.AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path).assetBundleName;
        var guid = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(path);

        this.AssetBundle = bundleName;
        this.AssetFullPath = path;
        this.GUID = guid;
    }

    public UnityEngine.Object GetRealObject()
    {
        // I'm not a unity3d developer so I am not sure this is the correct method to call.
        return UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(AssetFullPath, UnityType);
    }

    public string AssetFullPath;
    public string AssetBundle;
    public string GUID;
    public Type UnityType;
}

public class UnityObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(UnityEngine.Object).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var metadata = serializer.Deserialize<GameObjectMetadata>(reader);
        return metadata.GetRealObject();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // WriteJson is never called when value == null.  Instead Json.NET calls writer.WriteNull() directly.
        var metadata = new GameObjectMetadata((UnityEngine.Object)value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, metadata);
    }
}
```

There is no need for `GameObjectMetadataJsonConverter`.

Note I'm not a [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) developer so I am not sure [`AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(AssetFullPath, Type.GetType(UnityType))`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html) is the correct method to call to reconstruct a game object from its metadata, so replace with whatever is correct.

Comment: Rock solid! Thanks a lot mate. And very close on the guess at the Unity API for GetRealObject() ;)